# When it is good to compile shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to move into the 'modern' OpenGL. I think I understand so far the concept of `shader`s and I know how to compile them, but I'm not sure about when it is good to do it.

Is it ok to have a function that would compile all `shader`s at the application start up, store them in some kind of manager, which would serve currently needed `shader`?

Or maybe should I just compile them when they are needed and the next time they're needed just use the one I've already created?

And I assume that creating a `shader program` every frame is not a good idea.

I'd appreciate any hints about it how to organise it in a good way.

Comment: How much does performance matter to your application?

Comment: Not very much, but I wouldn't also like to encounter a big performance drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to have a function that would compile all shaders at the application start up, store them in some kind of manager, which would serve currently needed shader?

Yes. This is one of those one-time initialization things that could be regarded as OpenGL "initialization".